# How to add drop down button for particular column (D) in openpyXL and change the background color of particular cell when one option is selected

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

Using `OpenPyXl`, can we have privilege to add drop down button (High and Low) like we have in `XlsxWriter` `data_validation()`; and add background color Green to entire row when `High` is selected and Red if `Low` is selected?

In `XlsxWriter` we have:

```py
format_green = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'green'})
format_red = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'red'})

# Apply the data validation rule
worksheet.data_validation('D2:D5', {'validate': 'list',
                            'source': ['High','Low']})

# Apply the conditional formating rules
worksheet.conditional_format('A2:D5', {'type': 'formula',
                            'criteria': '=$D2="High"',
                            'format': format_green})

worksheet.conditional_format('A2:D5', {'type': 'formula',
                            'criteria': '=$D2="Low"',

                            'format': format_red})
```

Do we have similar functionality when using `OpenPyXl`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is both [Conditional Formatting](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html) and [Data Validation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validation.html) in `OpenPyXl`.

Here is an example of Conditional Formatting:

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import *
from openpyxl.formatting import Rule
from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill, Border, Alignment
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import CellIsRule

wb = load_workbook("./document.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

ws.conditional_formatting.add('A2:D5', CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0'],font = Font(color = '00FF0000')))

wb.save('document.xlsx')
```